# Coercion Failed issue

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, workflow-variable

I have this issue, it´s a simple workflow: users have to input two dates and the workflow should wait until one of those dates and send an email when that date is "today". It just doesn´t work at all, i try using a variable so i can copy the date on it and then compare the variable with the server date but it doesn´t work neither. It´s SharePoint 2010.

Help please.

Comment: what are you doing? are you pausing until that date?

Comment: I compare the variable and the date, if it´s greater or iqual it should send the email, if it´s not i pause until the date and then send the email.

Comment: I solved it on my own. The problema was a hyperlink in the email i was sending.